# Automatic Mails in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When changes occur on some reservation I want everyone involved getting a mail about the changes.

Actually I am not sure how to get this done. But I geuss my first question should be.
How should I check if changes have accord and how am I suppose to know which person people are involved in the changes?

I am using Entity Framework ( Lazy Loading ) in MVC 3.

Comment: you should build this logic into your functions that are responsible for creating/editing reservations. Presumable the people involved with be linked to the reservation with a database relationship - how this works is all down to your design, which we know nothing of

Comment: You give us very little information. First you have to find the users you want to email and their email addresses. Are the users in the database? Is there any reference between the "reservations" table and users? Then you have to have a SMTP server that can send the mails. Wherever in your code you save any changes you could create email messages and send to the concerned users. Have a look at the MailMessage class in .NET. A SMTP server is often set up (and maintained) by your IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deltu,

this can be resolved in a number of ways. the one that I use today is based on raising an event when the repository is saving changes. not sure what your configuration looks like, but here's a snippet of what I do:

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
    //_auditDate = DateTime.Now; ignore this in your case
    OnSavingChanges();
    _context.SaveChanges();
    OnSavedChanges();
}

private void OnSavingChanges()
{
    if (SavingChanges != null)
    {
        var eventArgs = new RepositorySavingChangesEventArgs()
        {
            AuditDate = _auditDate
        };
        SavingChanges(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
public event EventHandler<RepositorySavingChangesEventArgs> SavingChanges;

private void OnSavedChanges()
{
    if (SavedChanges != null)
    {
        var eventArgs = new RepositorySavedChangesEventArgs()
        {
            AuditDate = _auditDate
        };
        SavedChanges(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
public event EventHandler<RepositorySavedChangesEventArgs> SavedChanges;
```

then simple make sure that your client code subscribes to the SavingChanges EventHandler. Job done. You literally only subscribe within the context of where you know the crucial changes are and then fire off an email service call inseide that event handler.

hope this helps.

**[edit]** in response to comment below, you would raise either of these events in either the service class, the base abstract class, or more simply, in your controller. here's an example of the controller raising the event:

```
public TimelinesController(IRepository repository)
{
_serviceTasks = new TimelineService(repository);
    repository.SavedChanges +=
        new EventHandler<RepositorySavedChangesEventArgs>(repository_SavedChanges);
}

private void repository_SavedChanges(object sender, RepositorySavedChangesEventArgs e)
{
    var newDate = e.AuditDate;
    /* do something fancy with the audit date */
}
```

hope this points you in a more 'pointed' direction :)

Comment: +1, though the hassle with doing it this way is that you'd be effectively generating emails from your middle tier not your presentation tier. If you've separated them out then you may no longer have easy access to parts of MVC that you'd use to render HTML email templates, etc. - when I did this I ended up having to add an entire template engine to my middle tier just for this: we settled on Spark which in hindsight was horrible. However that was pre Razor and I think you can use that now in environments where you don't have an HttpContext etc.

Comment: Yes that helps a lot thanks. You gave me some very good information I should use. And a very fast response aswell.

Comment: cheers Rup - yeah, Razor makes this middle-tier access a h3ll of a lot easier than the webforms days. another way is to purpose your middle tier service to only garner the required email addresses and pass that up to the presentation layer for consumption via a logging mechanism or email service etc.. layers, layers. layers :)

Comment: deltu - glad to have been of help!!

Comment: Hmm I have a question, I thought i'd just put my repository "save" method on the part where you declared "RepositorySavingChangesEventArgs", but it doesn't work like that. Can you perhaps explain a bit about that?

Comment: deltu - it's a little more complex than that. you do of course need to raise that event, either in a service class (or abstract base), or more simply, in your controller. i'll edit my answer to show a controller events based scenario